# Entity Framework 6 seems to be ignoring HasDefaultSchema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, schema

I am working on a site where we'd like schema to be the differentiator between projects and in doing so, securing things up between projects.

I have had some luck with this using the `HasDefaultSchema` method in `OnModelCreating` in my data context, but also having to make my `DbContext` implement `IDbModelCacheKeyProvider` and implementing the `CacheKey` property. It has worked before. Unfortunately, this solution seems to be inconsistent and I am currently having a problem where I am trying to update my model but getting the following error when running `Update-Database`:

```
The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

The connection string has a user that only has access to my `xma` schema, so this error makes sense if I had changed the schema, but you can see in the following code, I haven't:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, DbModelCacheKeyProvider
{
    public DataContext()
        //: base("name=DataContext")
        : base("DataContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("xma");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    ...

    public string CacheKey
    {
        get { return Utility.SchemaPrefix ?? "xma"; }
    }
}
```

This problem occurs with other team members too, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention, this appears to be a problem on a clean database.

Comment: Do an "update-database -Script" and see where the dbo reference is.

Comment: I just tried that, I am getting the error `Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.`
I then tried adding a migration and I get the following error `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending:...`

Comment: If you are not too far along, might be best to reset migrations. Delete the folder in VS, delete __MigrationHistory in DB, enable-migrations, add-migration Initial -Ignore, update-database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed the pending changes to the model, and was able to run `update-database -script` as advised by Steve, turns out that the initial migrations are based on the dbo schema so changed to a more privileged user and was able to continue with recreating the database. My mistake unfortunately.